# Java XML getElementsByTagName() function

Tags: java, xml, getelementsbytagname

Lets say i have this XML file:

```
<attributes>
  <units>
    <civilians>
      <unit>
        <name>Settler</name>
        <stats>
          <attack>26</attack>
          <defence>7</defence>
        </stats>
        <costs>
          <lumber/>
          <iron/>
        </costs>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <name>Infantry</name>
        <stats>
          <attack>33</attack>
          <defence>7</defence>
        </stats>
        <costs>
          <lumber/>
          <iron/>
        </costs>
      </unit>
    </civilians>
  </units>
</attributes>
```

Does getElementsByTagName("attack") on the node attributes return a NodeList with the attack element containing 26 at first position and the attack element containing 33 at second position?

I've been thinking this is the case but it doesn't seem to work.

If it isn't as simple as this; what is a good way to grab all attack values from the XML file? Maybe the XML file itself is badly structured?

**Edit: Ah. I get the nodes now, and .getTextContent() rather than .getNodeValue() solved my problems. Sorry for the inconvenience.**

Comment: What behaviour are you getting instead?

Comment: Well i get the elements all right but they seem to have lost their values. When i do Nodes.item(0).getNodeValue() (nodes is the NodeList) i get null :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dom Core 2 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1938918D) says:

> **getElementsByTagName**
>
> Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag
>   name, in the order in which they are
>   encountered in a preorder traversal of
>   this Element tree.

And [Dom Core 3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1938918D) says:

> **getElementsByTagName**
>
> Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag
>   name, in document order.

So your expectations for the function are correct. If that's not what you're getting it would be a bug in your code or in the library you're using.

Comment: Glad to hear. Well now i do get the Elements but their values seem lost. When i do Nodes.item(i).getNodeValue() i get null in return :/

Comment: @Alexus48 - Right. You're getting the node value of the element. You need to get the value of the text node child of the element. I suggest Nodes.item(i).getTextContent(), or Nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()